# Modifying a struct in IEnumerable foreach vs List<T>.ForEach

Tags: c#, ienumerable

This question is specifically about structs.

Say I define:

```
struct Complex
{
    public double real, imaginary;
}
```

If I try:

```
var numbers = new[] 
{
    new Complex() { real = 1, imaginary = 1 },
    new Complex() { real = -1, imaginary = -1 } 
};

foreach ( var z in numbers )
{
    z.real += 1;
}
```

I get compilation error: `Error: cannot modify members of 'complex' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'`

However,

```
var numbers = new List<Complex>();
numbers.Add( new Complex() { real = 1, imaginary = 1 } );
numbers.Add( new Complex() { real = -1, imaginary = -1 } );

numbers.ForEach( z => z.real += 1 );
```

compiles with no error. Keeping the 'foreach' compilation error in mind, is there any reason for not giving a compile-time error here?

Comment: They're equally dangerous things to attempt, but one's easy for the compiler to spot, the other is very difficult.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR:

- C# *tries* to protect you from yourself
- If you try hard enough, you'll be able to do bad things - the language doesn't protect you from *every* stupid thing you might do
- Mutable structs are bad

> Is there any reason for not giving a compile-time error here then?

Yes. You're just modifying a parameter, which is absolutely fine. Parameters aren't deemed read-only, whereas the iteration variable in a `foreach` loop *is* deemed read-only. From section 8.8.4 of the C# 5 specification:

> During execution of a foreach statement, the iteration variable represents the collection element for which an iteration is currently being performed. A compile-time error occurs if the embedded statement attempts to modify the iteration variable (via assignment or the ++ and -- operators) or pass the iteration variable as a ref or out parameter.

None of this means that using a mutable variable is a good idea - and it also doesn't mean that your `ForEach` loop will do what you want it to. (The argument was passed to the delegate *by value* after all.)

If you really want to do something similar (equally ineffective, but hey...) in the `foreach` version, just write a *method* in the struct which mutates the fields, then call it from the loop. That's perfectly valid...

```
// Bad code! Valid, but horrible
foreach (var z in numbers)
{
    z.SetReal(z.real + 1);
}
```

It still won't modify the values in the list... but it won't fail at compile-time.

Comment: Glad I didn't bother answering since I knew Sir Skeet wasn't far behind.